# Cambiar tamaño del texto de varios textview al mismo tiempo desde código

Tags: android

Quiero tener varios botones que cambien el tamaño del texto de toda la aplicación.

Se que en el archivo `layout.xml` puedo modificar el tamaño manualmente o haciendo referencia a un dimension (@dimen/tamaño_letra), también se que desde el código puedo crear una referencia del objeto (widget) y usar el método `setTextSize()` pero el problema es que son cientos de `TextView` y necesito cambiar el tamaño del texto a todos al mismo tiempo.

No quiero tener que hacer mil referencias de todos los TextView para luego usar el metodo `setTextSize()`.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas.

¿Has intentado recorrer recursivamente el contenedor de tus botones? este código es de ejemplo, por lo que podría no funcionar:

```java
private void changeTextViewTextSize(ViewGroup v){
    for (int i = 0, length = v.getChildCount(); i < length; i++){
        Object child = v.getChildAt(i); 

        if (child instanceof TextView){
            TextView tv = (EditText)child;
            tv.setTextSize(12)
        } else if(child instanceof ViewGroup){
            changeTextViewTextSize((ViewGroup)child); 
        }
    }
}
```

Para llamar a esta funcion debes pasar como parametro el contenedor de todos tus textviews:

```
changeTextViewTextSize(R.id.textviewscontainer);
```